# Laravel 7 add React.js to project without composer require laravel/ui?

Tags: laravel

I need to connect React.js to Laravel 7.23 project with UIkit.css framework.
Standard solution

```
composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui react
php artisan ui react --auth
npm install
```

But, this solution includes bootstrap.css framework which I do not need.
I also found

```
php artisan preset react
```

But on execution I get "Command "preset" is not defined."

Comment: i'm looking for this same question, did you found a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`laravel-ui` is the new laravel frontend Scaffolding library. `php artisan preset` is no longer supported.

`php artisan ui react` will give you the react Scaffolding. There is no default option for `UIkit.css` If you do not need `bootstrap` just remove it and add something you want.

Hope that answers all your concerns.

Answer (score 0):

For installing react in laravel 7, refer to [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/frontend#using-react)

**Install laravel ui composer package**

```
composer require laravel/ui
```

**Install react**

```
 php artisan ui react
```

**Install react with auth**

```
 php artisan ui react --auth
```

Make sure you run `npm install` and `npm run dev`